# Possible to save progress of "refresh" in wallet (mid-refresh)?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet-recovery, refresh

Is it possible to save the progress of the `refresh` command in the `monero-wallet-cli` in the middle of a running `refresh` -- before it finishes reaching the end of the blockchain?

I need to pay an invoice, and I'd like to use Monero.

I'm currently traveling, so I can only work for a few hours before I have to fully shutdown my laptop.

I downloaded the latest monero CLI wallet software, and I restored my wallet from the seed:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --use-english-language-names --restore-deterministic-wallet
```

I'm also running `monerod` locally (I have my own local node on my laptop).

```
./monerod --offline
```

The monero `refresh` starts at block 0.

```
Starting refresh...
Height 0 / 2618360
```

After some hours, I need to shutdown my computer. It didn't finish the `refresh`, but it got a good chunk of it done.

After lunch, I boot my laptop again and open the wallet. But it's started the refresh back at block 0 again!

```
Starting refresh...
Height 0 / 2618360
```

I really like the idea of Monero, but I'm finding it quite impractical to use. And if I need to put my wallet in a server on the cloud, well, then it's not very secure..

Is there a way to save the progress of a wallet's `refresh` **in the middle of a refresh** so that the `refresh` can be done in-parts over several sessions between reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the progress of a wallet's `refresh` before it completes, but you have to exit the wallet safely.

You can pause a refresh by pressing "Ctrl+C" on your computer (send the `^C` SIGINT signal).

```
Starting refresh...
Height 0 / 261836060
Height 2352605 / 261836060
^C
Refresh done, blocks received: 66661                            
Untagged accounts:
          Account               Balance      Unlocked balance                 Label
...
Background refresh thread started
[wallet 45yY5A (out of sync)]:
```

Then use the `save` command to save the progress to the wallet's cache

```
[wallet 45yY5A (out of sync)]: save
Wallet data saved
```

Finally, exit the wallet safely with the `exit` command

```
[wallet 45yY5A (out of sync)]: exit
user@host:~$
```

When you open the wallet again, it will refresh where it left off.

But, if you just close the terminal or shutdown your computer, then it will *not* save this progress, and the `refresh` will start again at block 0.